# Mule SFTP credentials

Tags: mule, sftp

Mule 3.3.1 CE

The SFTP endpoint appears to have problems with user names with the '@' character in them.  For example, both of the following fail although the address works in other tools.

```
<sftp:outbound-endpoint address="sftp://test04@caqa.com:Test1234@testftpdev.caqa.com" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp].xml"/>

<sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp].xml" host="testftpdev.caqa.com" port="22" path="/" user="test04@caqa.com" password="Test1234" responseTimeout="10000"/>
```

The error message is:

```
Error during login to null@null
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: username must not be null.
...etc.
```

Trying against a site that allows user names without the '@' (e.g., 'test04') seems to work fine through the connector.

Since I have no control over the user names at some of the required target sites, does anyone know of a workaround for this?  It needs to run in 3.3.1 CE as we won't be onto 3.4 Enterprise for another couple of months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URL encode the name and password to take care of this situation.